# Select data from a couple of tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, `tab_ad` and `tab_photos`, each ad can have five photos (or any).

Structure:

> tab_ad
>
> - ad_id
> - ad_title
> - ad_desc
>
> tab_photos
>
> - ph_id
> - ph_path
> - ad_id

I'm trying to make a select that select all columns of the `tab_ad` and the first photo on the `tab_photos` (each ad_id) and if I don't find the ad_id on `tab_photos` should return **NULL**.

> Example: return ad_id, ad_title, ad_desc, ph_id, ph_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `correlated sub query` hence you want to select the `top photo` from the second table.

```
SELECT 
    ad_id,
    ad_title,
    ad_desc,
    (SELECT TOP(1)ph_path FROM tab_photos b WHERE b.ad_id=a.ad_ID)
FROM tab_ad a
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `LEFT JOIN` it will give values of `tab_photos` as `NULL` if the data (i.e. `ad_id`) is not available there :

```
SELECT ad.ad_id, ad.ad_title, ad.ad_desc, ph.ph_id, ph.ph_path
  FROM tab_ad ad 
  LEFT JOIN tab_photos ph
    ON ad.ad_id = ph.ad_id
```

Comment: is this result multiple rows while `tab_photos ` contains more than one photo for one `ad_id`??